# how to give id for Button By Dynamic Creations in Android?

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to create a button by Dynamically and also i created .Now i want to write the function for click Event So i need the id for Button.I Dont know How to Create id for button Dynamically.Guide me
Thanks in Advance
Here My coding

```
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        sv.addView(ll);
        Button main=new Button(this);
        CharSequence value="Main +";
        main.setText(value);
        ll.addView(main);
           }
        this.setContentView(sv);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set id of any controls by

```
btn.setId(integer value) at runtime.
```

If you don't want to set id then there is no issue

Also when you create new view then you have to set its `layout parameters(Height, Width)`

for example

```
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So whole process is like

```
Button btn = new Button(Context);
btn.setId(1);
btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btn.setText("Dynamic button");
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Dynamic button is clicked", 3000).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
Button text = new Button(this);

text.setId(1);
text.setText("text here");
ll.addView(text);
text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int id = arg0.getId(); // you get ID of your dynamic button
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dynamic textview!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

In that "ll" is a Layout and that add button.
after that you use anytime for click execute that clickListener code.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this

```
Button main= new Button(this);
            main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

and there is `main.setId(pass here int value);` to set id but i think you will not need it